# how is merge and split not in scope? (haskell)

Tags: haskell, merge, split

i tried to program a code for sorting a list of integers, however i got a error message from terminal, Code and Errors are shown below:

```
-- sort
type Element = Int
merge_sort :: [Element] -> [Element]
merge_sort list = case list of
  [] -> []
  [x] -> [x]
  _  -> merge (merge_sort(list_left)) (merge_sort(list_right))
     where (list_left, list_right) = split list
```

And i got the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( recursion test.hs, interpreted )

recursion test.hs:7:9: Not in scope: `merge'

recursion test.hs:8:42: Not in scope: `split'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Who likes to tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: What is merge anyway? There is no merge function in your script.

Comment: Well that means that neither `merge` nor `split` functions are defined.

Comment: oh, but i thought they are both built-in funcs ?  @Felix && bereal

Comment: @bereal haskell is so confusing

Comment: Sometimes it is, but I don't know many languages that allow calling undefined functions. You can check [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find functions in the standard libs.

Comment: @bereal, alright, thanks alot, yea you u right, we got to define it ourself.... damn, i thought its built-in

Comment: Actually, `merge` is defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/0.18.6/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3Amerge), and for `split` you can use [`splitAt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:splitAt)

Comment: oah, yea, here is it, i guess i used the wrong format for merge....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I'm just going to put a few of the comments in an answer so this question can be marked as answered.*

`merge` isn't defined in Prelude but you can get it with

```
import Data.List.Utils (merge)
```

`split` isn't defined, but fear not:

```
split ls = splitAt (length ls `div` 2) ls
```

which requires you to

```
import Data.List
```

Haskell has lots of these functions in its standard library. They aren't "built in"* but there available for use. If you want to find one, I'd use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

** Most languages are like this nowadays, Haskell isn't unique here.